# Report design using stored procedures in Report builder (SSRS)?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to use stored procedures for designing Reports in Report builder?

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking if it's possible to use sprocs in SSRS reports that you create, then yes.  Just call the sproc in the query for your DataSet like you would normaly.

Answer (score 3):

In Report Builder 1.0 (SSRS 2005), the answer is No. (unless you perform special tricks with table functions)

In Report Builder 2.0 (SSRS 2008), the answer is Yes. (stored procedures are readily available in the GUI)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle on the backend, you can query the results of a table function (a stored function that returns a TABLE of TYPE).  The query string for your Dataset will look like:

```
select * from table (f_foo(:p_bar))
```

...where f_foo is your table function stored in the database and p_bar is a report parameter to f_foo.  More info on table functions here:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2222781

Answer (score 0):

Both  SSRS 2005/2008  its possible to get data through stored procedure, in ssrs 2005 while creating dataset command type we need to select stored procedure and in ssrs 2008 while creating dataset the query type we need to select stored procedure.